# How to add a link inside a D3 element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I am trying to add links on a radial calendar using D3, where each day on the calendar contains a link that would show more details about that specific day. I am using this calendar as a base: http://jsfiddle.net/dmann99/q63WN/

For example, let's say I want to add a link to "google.com" on the days that are filled in (weekends).

```
// Draw faint arcs for each day (weekends filled, else outlined).
vis.selectAll("g.AllDays")
.data(dates)
.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "AllDays")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r1 + "," + r1 + ")")
.append("svg:path")
    .attr("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.hsl(0,0.25,0.75) })     
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return (d.getDay()==5||d.getDay()==6)?"#cccccc":"#ffffff";
     })
    .attr("d", arc)
;
```

Is there a way for me to add a link on the specific days that are filled in and not the whole calendar?

I tried adding something like this, but it didn't work:

```
.on("click", function() { window.open("http://google.com"); });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pointer-events style property seems to be the key here (i.e. it doesn't work without it)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events

```
    .filter (function(d) { return d.getDay() ==5 || d.getDay() ==6; })
    .on("click", function() { window.open("http://google.com", "_blank"); })
```

css rule needed:

```
.WeekLine {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

It was originally working with just the javascript change above when clicking weekend nodes around the edge of the display, but the .WeekLine circles were intercepting the mouse events for clicks in the interior of the display.

http://jsfiddle.net/q63WN/5/

(so pointer-events was still the thing to fiddle with, I just focused on the wrong elements to start with...)

Comment: Great solution! Is there any way to change the cursor style to "pointer" when it hovers over a clickable cell?

Comment: Never mind. I added .style("cursor","pointer") and it works great!